# Temporary UIImage never clearing

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, swift

I Need Download one image and show on `ImageView`, however after display it, I need to delete the image from device. But always When I open the application again the image is already loaded.

code:

```
func getPhoto(pathPhoto: String, imageview: UIImageView) {

        activityIndicator = UIActivityIndicatorView(frame: CGRectMake(20, 20, imageview.frame.size.width - 40, imageview.frame.size.height - 40))
        activityIndicator.color = UIColor(red: 64.0/255.0, green: 109.0/255.0, blue: 157.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
        activityIndicator.startAnimating()
        imageview.addSubview(activityIndicator)

        var photoUrlString = urlImages

        photoUrlString += pathPhoto

        var imgURL: NSURL = NSURL(string: photoUrlString)!
        let request: NSURLRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: imgURL)
        NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request, queue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue(), completionHandler: {(response: NSURLResponse!,data: NSData!,error: NSError!) -> Void in
            if error == nil {
                if data == nil {
                    NSLog("Erro ao baixar")
                } else {
                    self.image = UIImage(data: data)

                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                        self.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
                        self.activityIndicator.removeFromSuperview()
                        imageview.image = self.image
                    })
                }
            }
        })
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is that `NSURLConnection` automatically caches responses to HTTP requests locally. So while you may not be saving the image in the app's directory, the system is saving it for you.

How you handle this depends on why you're deleting the image on the device. If it's because you want to serve a fresh image every time, and you have control over the server, it might make sense to fix this there by setting the proper HTTP headers to tell clients not to cache the image.

If you have some sort of data security reason in mind, you can clear the cache manually, either the [entire thing](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLCache_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSURLCache/removeAllCachedResponses) or [just one request](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLCache_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSURLCache/removeCachedResponseForRequest:).

There's also a good [NSHipster article](http://nshipster.com/nsurlcache/) about NSURLCache.